# Spartacus v3: Cannot navigate to "review-order" from "payment-details" after migration from v2

Tags: spartacus-storefront

When on checkout step "payment details", I cannot navigate to "review order" via next button. Every other step works as expected.

Once clicked, I can see the loading bar appearing, the debugger also stopping in the `checkoutStepService.next()` with the correct URL but the route or view do not change.

Did I miss any new needed configuration for the checkout steps?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In v3 it seems Spartacus wants payment details in `checkout-step-sets.guard.ts` as well.

I have simply overwritten the guard's method which asks for it:

```
export class CustomCheckoutStepsSetGuard extends CheckoutStepsSetGuard {
  isPaymentDetailsSet(): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {
    return of(true)
  }
}
```